# How do I mock a custom field that is deleted so that south migrations run?

Tags: django, data-migration, django-south

I have removed an app that contained a couple of custom fields from my project. Now when I try to run my migrations I get `ImportError`, naturally. These fields were very basic customizations like below:

```
from django.db.models.fields import IntegerField

class SomeField(IntegerField):
    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "SomeField"

    def db_type(self, connectio=None):
        return 'integer'

    def clean(self, value):
        # some custom cleanup
        pass
```

So, none of them contain any database level customizations.

When I removed this code, I've created migrations so the subsequent migration all ran fine. But when I try to run them on a pre-deletion database I realized my mistake.

I can re-create a bare-bones app and make these imports work, but Ideally I would like to know if South has a mechanism to resolve these issues? Or is there any best practises? It would be cool if I could solve these issues just by modifying my migrations and not touching the codebase.

(Django 1.3, South 0.7.3)

Answer (score 2):

South does not hold a reference of deleted field in afterwards migrations. If you deleted the customized field and generated migration successfully, `ImportError` probably caused by that those customized fields are still referenced by some undone migrations before the deletion migration. So

1. update the code base to the version right before you do the packaging-removing and deletion migration
2. migrate
3. update code base to the deletion migration and migrate

Comment: Right. But I'd like to explore options that doesn't involve rewinding my VCS. After all, I should be able to seed a database using HEAD.

Comment: @muhuk I've no idea there is such thing. However, you could change migrations as long as its right in logic and works well for the schema on production DB and generating test DB. For example, you could simply delete latest migrations that just add and then remove some field, or modify models lines inside migration files to delete certain field. Do it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Such simple custom fields are very easy with South 0.7+ if `add_introspection_rules` [[1](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part4.html.)] have been defined for them. (in the same module after custom field class), when migration was created. Then South does not "freeze" these fields and they can be easily removed. Then if the previous answer from okm does not help you, recreate the old migrations correctry.